# Until quantifier of Computation Tree Logic

Tags: terminology, logic, temporal-logic

It's quite a short question: Refering to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic) `p U q` means, that *`p` has to hold at least until at some point `q` holds*.

So, does it mean:

1. On each path starting from the current state `p` has to hold in each state until a state is reached in which `q` holds.
2. On each path starting from the current state `p` has to hold in any state before a state is reached in which `q` holds.

**Example**: Suppose `p` holds in `s3` and `q` holds in `s5`. Let `s0` be the starting state and the set of edges given by `{ (s0,s1),(s1,s2),(s2,s3),(s3,s4),(s4,s5) }`. Let's assume `p` and `q` don't hold in all the other states. Is `p U q` satisfied, starting from `s0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$pUq$, as is, is not a well-formulated CTL (or more generally - CTL*) formula. A CTL* formula is a *state* formula, which starts with has a path quantifier ($A$ or $E$).

$pUq$ is a *path* formula, which means it refers to a single (linear) computation. A computation satisfies $pUq$ if $p$ holds in every state until $q$ holds (and $q$ must hold at some state).

Translating to CTL, you can talk about two different formulas: $ApUq$ and $EpUq$. The former is true in a state if every path starting from this state satisfies $pUq$. The latter is true in a state if there exists such a path starting from that state.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks a lot. One further question: If I get the things write, if a state holds `p U q` then, `p` must hold in that state. Is that true?

Comment: $pUq$ is a path formula, so I guess you mean something like $ApUq$ or $EpUq$. In that case - either $p$ or $q$ must hold in that state. If $q$ holds, then the eventuality is immediately fulfilled.

Comment: So, `A[p U q]` and `E[p U q]` are fulfilled when `q` holds in the current state. Even if `p` doesn't hold in that state? Seems to make sense. Thanks again.

Comment: That is correct.